# Why was Tobi not proactive after all missing nins got recruited for Akatsuki?

Tags: naruto

As far as I know, Tobi didn't come to limelight until Sasori's death (I am talking as per the chronological order of the telly series). He teamed up with Deidara after Sasori's death. He knew Nagato and his team long back but he was not proactive with the organization at the beginning of series.

Why didn't he volunteer himself? Is it because Akatsuki work in pairs and he didn't have anyone? Or was he waiting for the right moment to join with the organization?

Comment: It most likely has to be that Obito was just waiting for the right chance. With Nagato being the acting head of Akatsuki, he wouldn't want to just come in and take over because the members wouldn't like that either. Obito was the brains behind the execution of the plan though.

Comment: please do put that as an answer!!!!

Comment: Its a bit small to be posted as an answer. Also, I don't have any references to support my answer. I'd probably post one when I get some off time(ofcourse if there isn't any other answer by then) :)

Comment: sure.....ur answer would be really appreciated if u come with some facts.....although i thought like u initially but i need to understand what do others think about it..... ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tobi was the brain behind the plan. But he used Nagato to carry out his plan. He exploited Nagato's hatred towards big countries. He was dead as obito for the world. So he wanted to hide and work behind the scene so that he could keep his identity hidden from all before he could collect all bijuus. Also, Land of Rain was always a secretive nation. And Akatsuki already had strong base. It gave him a perfect place to hide himself. But towards the end as more and more akatsuki members died he was forced to come to limelight.

Comment: but wouldn't it been better he was active from the start itself?

Comment: he could have avoided the death of akatsuki members.....

Comment: yeah but he wanted to collect bijuus. except this he didn't have any use of aktsuki. as long as they got bijuus his plan was good. an also akatsuki was able to capture all biijuus except 8 an 9tails. considering their high success rate why would he interfere in their work as they are wiling to complete his work for him.